# Centering rotated text in <td>

Tags: html, css

How to vertically center "There is information text" here?
Better - without changing html.

Also why doesn't `max-width: 15px!important` limit the width of the first `<td>` (tall) to `15px`? How to limit it without changing the general width parameter?

```css
td {width: 60px}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="max-width: 15px!important;" rowspan="12">
                <p style="transform: rotate(270deg); white-space: nowrap">There is information text</p>
            </td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**It is need to center it so without rotation to make it work with:**
[image]
**Is it possible? It is the most interesting for me.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use rotation but adjust the [`writing-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode). The text will get centred and you no more need to force the width:

```css
td:not([rowspan]) {
  width: 60px
}

p {
  margin:5px;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: scale(-1);
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="12">
        <p>There is information text</p>
      </td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Or like below:

```css
td:not([rowspan]) {
  width: 60px
}

p {
  margin:5px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  max-width:15px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  transform:rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="12">
        <p>There is information text</p>
      </td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215168/discussion-on-answer-by-temani-afif-centering-rotated-text-in-td).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `transform: rotate(270)` to rotate your text, the `vertical-align: middle` doesn't work anymore for the content of your `<td>`.

What  you can use is add `translateX(...)` to adjust your text's placement. This won't work for dynamic content though.

Comment: But how to combine `rotate` and `translateX` in syntax?

Comment: You can simply append it along with rotate: `transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);`

Comment: Ok. But the baddest is that need to find the optimal parameter for centering. So it is not suitable for auto creating tables (with different height and text).

Comment: Yes, definitely not suitable for auto-creating. The optimal solution is to compute the width of the text then use half of that to `translateX(...)`.

Comment: Do you mean the element width? Seems not possible to compute the width of exactly the text in JS. Yes? Or possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think this may solve your question with the use of rotation

```css
td { width:60px}
p{
 margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(270deg);
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="max-width: 15px!important;position:relative;" rowspan="12">
                <p style="white-space: nowrap">There is information text</p>
            </td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, it solves. Possible without `position: absolute`?

Comment: As i used no , maybe there are another ways , i will get back to you if i found another one